# Is there a better way to require file from relative path in lua

Tags: lua

My directory structure looks like this:

```
|-- ball.lua
|-- entity.lua
|-- test
    `-- ball_test.lua
```

I'm using the following code in test/ball_test.lua to require ball.lua from the parent directory:

```
package.path = package.path .. ";../entity.lua"
require("entity")
package.path = package.path .. ";../ball.lua"
require("ball")
```

entity.lua is a dependency of ball.lua. So I require("entity") first otherwise I get a module 'entity.lua' not found error. This seems like a hack, what's a better way to do this?

Comment: have ball module require entity.lua, so you just have to require'ball'

Comment: @Lukasz - ball does require entity.lua. I get the error because require can't find entity.lua when it's executed from the test subdirectory. Sorry I didn't make that clear in my question.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
package.path = package.path .. ";../?.lua"
```

will work for both.

Comment: I would switch this around to `package.path = ";../?.lua" .. package.path` so I don't have unknown modules beating the local ones.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant ``package.path = "../?.lua;" .. package.path`` (the path delimiter should be moved). Otherwise, good idea.

Comment: +1 for anyone looking for how to do this for C extension modules, you need to modify `package.cpath` not `package.path`; otherwise it is much the same

Comment: this is bad idea if you use NGINX LUA modul. package.path is global. Each request, this code executed and concate infinitely. At the end, it will explose. I have a bad experience in PROD with this code. Please use lua_package_path instead. Read this article also https://medium.com/@fabricebaumann/how-we-reduced-the-cpu-usage-of-our-lua-code-cc30d001a328

    lua_package_path ";;/your/folder/lua/?.lua" ;

_;;_ is a symbolic link to your defaut package lua directory. Do not remove it.

Answer (score -1):

This might be a alternative **https://github.com/yogeshlonkar/lua-import**

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this module

Comment: why didn't you vote to close as a duplicate?