# Is it possible to make imports depend on the location of my Lua script instead of the current directory?

Tags: lua

If I have two scripts that reference each other on the same directory

```
A/
   foo.lua
   bar.lua
```

foo.lua

```
require "bar"
```

bar.lua

```
print "It worked"
```

then running the lua executable from the same folder works

```
cd A; lua foo.lua
```

but running the interpreter from another folder fails with a "module 'bar' not found" message

```
cd A/..; lua A/foo.lua
```

Is there a way to have my relative imports not depend on the current working directory? For example, in batch files I can setup my paths to be relative to `dirname $0`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to require file from relative path in lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761229/is-there-a-better-way-to-require-file-from-relative-path-in-lua)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that `package.path` doesn't consider the directory the running script is in.  While Doug's solution works this can become tedious if you have to keep adding

```
package.path = 'foobar_path/?.lua;'..package.path
```

to scripts you plan on running from a different working directory. What you can do to make it easier is create a module that automatically adds the running script's directory to `package.path` when you require it. This module would reside in one of the default locations listed in `package.path` so it can be found.

```
-- moduleroot.lua
local moduleroot = arg and arg[0]
if moduleroot then
  local path = moduleroot:match [[^(.+[\/])[^\/]+$]]
  if path and #path > 0 then
    package.path = path..'?.lua;'..package.path
    package.cpath = path..'?.dll;'..package.cpath
    return path
  end
end
```

---

```
-- foo.lua
require "moduleroot"
require "bar"
```

In fact, this is a common enough problem that **[Penlight](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight)** includes a convenience facility for handling this: **[`pl.app.require_here`](http://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/modules/pl.app.html#require_here)**.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is to update `package.path` to contain the parent of `A` (or put `A` on the path). Then use `require` and refer to the modules as `A.bar` and `A.foo`

See the [manual entry on `require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require)

It is possible to find the directory using [`debug.getinfo`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.getinfo) but using the `debug` module in applications is not a great idea, and not necessary in this case.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761229/is-there-a-better-way-to-require-file-from-relative-path-in-lua) related SO question -- use `package.path`.