# Lua: require fails to find submodule, but searchpath succeeds?

Tags: lua, require

usually when I have a question about something remotely software related I find that someone else has already asked the very same thing, and gotten good answers that works for me too.

This time, though, I've failed to find an answer to my predicament.

Here we go:
I'm currently trying to move up my Lua-programming a notch or three and want to use modules. So, I've got a structure like this:

```
main.lua
foo/bar.lua
```

Now, in main.lua I do

```
require("foo.bar")
```

which fails,

```
main.lua:1 module 'foo.bar' not found:
     no field package.preload['foo.bar']
     no file 'foo.bar.lua'
     no file 'foo.bar.lua'
     no file 'foo.lua'
```

Ok, something might be wrong with my `package.path` so I use  `package.searchpath("foo.bar", package.path)` to see what I', doing wrong.

The problem is that `package.searchpath` resolves `foo.bar` to `foo/bar.lua` which is exactly right.

As I've understood it, package.searchpath tries to find the module in the same way as require, but there seems to be som glitch in my case.

What strikes me as odd is the repetition of the `no file 'foo.bar.lua'` in the error output

Have I misunderstood the use of require?

I'm using LuaJIT-2.0.0 to run my chunks

---

**Update:**

*I'm using LuaJIT-2.0.0 to run my chunks* **<- This was the reason for my problem, stock Lua-5.2.2 behaves as expected**

Comment: Can you try it in stock Lua from lua.org?

Comment: Can you include what `package.path` is on your setup?

Comment: **[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714204/is-it-possible-to-make-imports-depend-on-the-location-of-my-lua-script-instead-o/18042670#18042670)** might be related.

Comment: @lhf, I tried it with Lua-5.2.2 and it worked as a charm... the fault lies in LuaJIT it seems.

Comment: @greatwolf , I'll try your approach to work around the problems with LuaJIT (unfortunately, changing this is not an option at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

```
package.path = debug.getinfo(1,"S").source:match[[^@?(.*[\/])[^\/]-$]] .."?.lua;".. package.path
require("foo.bar")
```

> This line causes `require` to look in the same directory as the
>   current file when asked to load other files. If you want it to instead
>   search a directory relative to the current directory, insert the
>   relative path between " and ?.lua

**Here is part of require description:**

> [...] Otherwise require searches for a Lua loader using the path stored in
>   `package.path`. If that also fails, it searches for a C loader using the
>   path stored in package.cpath. If that also fails, it tries an
>   all-in-one loader (see `package.loaders`).

Default path for package.path is always the .exe that executes specified script.

Comment: I think that explains my problem, I'm calling the script as `../luajit main.lua`. Will verify this tomorrow!