# How to structure internal dependencies in a Lua library?

Tags: lua

I'm struggling to figure out how to structure and then use internal dependencies in a Lua library I'm writing.

I've defined my library like this:

```
./alib.lua
./alib/adependency.lua
```

And the code:

```
-- File: ./alib.lua
local ad = require "alib.adependency"
module( "alib")
return {}

-- File: ./alib/adependency.lua
module( "adependency" )
return {}
```

This works a treat:

```
$ lua alib.lua
<no output>
```

Now let's "add" this library into another app:

```
./anapp.lua
./lib/alib.lua
./lib/alib/adependency.lua
```

And the new code:

```
-- File: ./anapp.lua
local alib = require "lib.alib"
local print = print
module( "anapp")
print "Hello"
```

Try to run it:

```
$ lua anapp.lua
lua: ./lib/alib.lua:2: module 'alib.adependency' not found:
    no field package.preload['alib.adependency']
    no file './alib/adependency.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/alib/adependency.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/alib/adependency/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/alib/adependency.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/alib/adependency/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/alib/adependency.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/alib/adependency/init.lua'
    no file './alib/adependency.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/alib/adependency.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/alib/adependency.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/alib/adependency.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
    no file './alib.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/alib.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/alib.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/alib.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ./lib/alib.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    anapp.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Oh dear. Now I make a manual edit inside the library:

```
-- File: ./lib/alib.lua
-- local ad = require "alib.adependency" -- Doesn't work
local ad = require "lib.alib.adependency" -- Works
module( "alib")
return {}
```

And it works:

```
$ lua anapp.lua
Hello
```

It seems that Lua's `require()` relates paths relative to the ultimate script being run by Lua, not the script in which the `require()` is called.

Surely you don't have to manually fix the internal paths `require()`d inside of a Lua library every time you add one to your project... And I don't see how this can work from a unit test perspective either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cleanest solution is to leave your library as it was, and then make whomever is using your library responsible for configuring the `package.path` correctly. In your setup that means the application should add the lib folder to the path:

```
package.path = './lib/?.lua;' .. package.path
```

See also related questions like [Is there a better way to require file from relative path in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761229/is-there-a-better-way-to-require-file-from-relative-path-in-lua?lq=1) as well as [the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.path) for more about the path.

Comment: Yes; alternatively, install the lib in a directory on Lua's default path, like `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/`