# How to organize Lua module path and write "require" calls without losing flexibility?

Tags: module, lua

Say I have a project, whose folder structure looks like below:

```
| main.lua
|
|---<model> // this is a folder
|    |a.lua
|    |b.lua
|
|---<view>
     |a.lua
     |b.lua
```

**model/a.lua** requries **model/b.lua**: `require "b"`

**view/a.lua** requries **view/b.lua**: `require "b"`

**main.lua** requries files in **model** and **view**.

---

Now I have problem to get these modules loaded correctly. I know I can fix it by changing the require calls to:

**model/a.lua**: `require "model.b"`

**view/a.lua**: `require "view.b"`

But if I do that, I have to modify these files every time when I change the folder structure.

**So my questions are:**

1. How to fix the module path issue without hard code paths in module files?
2. Why Lua doesn't use the module search rule of Node.js, which looks easier?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you `require` a module, the string parameter from `require` gets passed into the module which you can access using the variable-argument syntax `...`. You can use this to include other dependent modules which reside in the *same path* as the current module being `require`ed without making it dependent on a fixed hard-coded module name.

For your example, instead of doing:

```
-- model/a.lua
require "model.b"
```

and

```
-- view/a.lua
require "view.b"
```

You can do:

```
-- model/a.lua
local thispath = select('1', ...):match(".+%.") or ""
require(thispath.."b")
```

and

```
-- view/a.lua
local thispath = select('1', ...):match(".+%.") or ""
require(thispath.."b")
```

Now if you change directory structure, eg. move `view` to something like `control/subcontrol/foobar`, then `control/subcontrol/foobar/a.lua` (formerly `view/a.lua`) will now try to require `control/subcontrol/foobar/b.lua` instead and "*do the right thing*".

Of course `main.lua` will still need to fully qualify the paths since you need some way to disambiguate between `model/a.lua` and `view/a.lua`.

Answer (score 3):

> How to fix the module path issue without hard code paths in module files?

I don't have any better cross-platform solution, maybe you should plan the folder structure early on.

> Why Lua doesn't use the module search rule of Node.js, which looks easier?

Because Lua tries its best to rely only on ANSI C, which is really successful. And in ANSI C, there's no such concept of directories.

Comment: Thanks for your editing and answer. But projects always go big from small, and they always need refactor. It's really difficult to make a plan at early phases. As to no external dependency except ANSI C, I agree it's a big advantage. But this doesn't conflict with a more portable module search rule.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple approaches you can use.

You can add relative paths to `package.path` as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761229/is-there-a-better-way-to-require-file-from-relative-path-in-lua). In your case you'd want to add paths in `main.lua` that correspond to the various ways you might access the files. This keeps all the changes required when changing your directory structure local to one file.

You can add absolute paths to `package.path`using `debug.getinfo` -- this may be a little easier since you don't need to account for all the relative accesses, but you still need to do this in `main.lua` when changing your directory structure, and you need to do string manipulation on the value returned by `debug.getinfo` to strip the module name and add the subdirectory names.

```
> lunit = require "lunit"
> info = debug.getinfo(lunit.run, "S")
> =info.source
@/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/lunit.lua
> =info.short_src
/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/lunit.lua
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add the folder of `main.lua` (project root) to `package.path` in `main.lua`.

A naive way to support folders of 1 level deep:

```
-- main.lua
package.path = package.path .. ";../?.lua"
```

> Note for `require`s in (project root) will look up files outside of project root, which is not desirable.

A better way of to use some library (e.g.: [paths](https://github.com/torch/paths), [penlight](http://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/libraries/pl.path.html)) to resolve the absolute path and add it instead:

```
-- main.lua
local projectRoot = lib.abspath(".")
package.path = package.path .. ";" .. projectRoot .. "/?.lua"
```

Then in you source use the folder name to scope the files:

```
-- model/a.lua
require "model.b"
-- you can even do this
require "view.b"
```

and

```
-- view/a.lua
require "view.b"
```