# Setting the require search path for Lua scripts

Tags: lua, require

I'm trying to use `require` from a Lua script which I load using `luaL_loadstring`.

Here's my code:

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
lua_settop(L, 0);
const char *script = "require('test.lua')";
const int ret = luaL_loadstring(L, script);
if (ret || lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))
{
    std::cout << "Error: " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << std::endl;
}
lua_close(L);
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error.

```
Error: [string "require('test.lua')"]:1: module 'test.lua' not found:
no field package.preload['test.lua']
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/test/lua.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/test/lua/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/test/lua.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/test/lua/init.lua'
no file './test/lua.lua'
no file './test/lua/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/test/lua.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
no file './test/lua.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/test.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
no file './test.so'
```

Is it possible to set the search path for Lua scripts so I can use `require` using the relative path?

Comment: You have to adjust `package.path` as detailed in [6.3 Modules](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.3). 
 From the C-API you require modules using [`luaL_requiref`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_requiref).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to require file from relative path in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761229/is-there-a-better-way-to-require-file-from-relative-path-in-lua)

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing the script to `const char *script =
    "package.path = package.path .. ';../?.lua'\
     require('test.lua')";` but it still produces the same error. I don't really understand why this question is a duplicate.

Comment: `require('test')`.  If you `require('test.lua')` the searcher will look for `test/lua.lua` (as you can see from the log).

Comment: BTW, instead of `luaL_loadstring` followed by `lua_pcall` you can simply use [`luaL_dostring`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_dostring).

Comment: Use `dofile` instead of `require`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make it to work using the following code thanks to @Henri_Menke.

```
/* set the current working directory */
const char *currentDir = "directory/to/script";
chdir(currentDir);
/* init lua and run script */
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
lua_settop(L, 0);
const char *script = "require('test')";
const int ret = luaL_loadstring(L, script);
if (ret || lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))
{
    std::cout << "Error: " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << std::endl;
}
lua_close(L);
```